# EF и вычисляемое поле с пользовательскими данными

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане. Помогите пожалуйста со след. вопросами:
Есть БД и подход построения код ферст и есть сущность, которая содержит поля координат X и Y:

```
public double X{get;set;}
public double Y{get;set;}
```

При получении данных, необходимо сделать сортировку ( на стороне БД) по расстоянию относительно координат (0,0).
насколько  я понимаю данный вопрос можно решить введением вычисляемого поля:

```
public virtual double Distance
{
  get{
         return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2));
       }
}
```

и запрос соответственно будет:

```
var list = dbcontext.where(условие).OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();
```

вроде как должно работать....
Но возникает вопрос, а можно как-то сделать, чтобы пользователь сам смог задавать центр отсчета и дистанция рассчитывалась относительно него, т.е.:

```
public virtual double Distance
{
  get{
         return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((X - UserX), 2) + Math.Pow((Y - UserY), 2));
       }
}
```

вопрос в том как передать в вычисление пользовательские UserX и UserY?
Поле Distance будет рассчитываться на стороне БД?
И еще в выражении где находиться list, насколько я понимаю, сортировка будет происходить на стороне БД? или уже на стороне сервера?
За ранее огромное спасибо всем:)

Comment: всем огромное спасибо за комментарии (очень интересно и для меня как не совсем опытного очень полезно) и помощь. На данном этапе разрешил вопрос след. образом:
from n in Context.MyTable
let distance = SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(SqlFunctions.Square(n.X - UserX) + SqlFunctions.Square(n.Y - UserY))
orderby distance

Answer (score 5):

> вроде как должно работать

Не должно.

EF, как и другой LINQ-провайдер, умеет отображать в SQL только заранее предопределенные свойства или вызовы методов.

Код, который вы пишете в `Where` или `OrderBy` компилируется не напрямую в IL, а в инициализацию древовидной структуры - Expression Tree. EF преобразует этот Expression Tree в SQL. Как только он находит в нем что-то неподдерживаемое, он падает с ошибкой вида

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'double get_Distance()', and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

И обойти это никак нельзя - нет способа преобразовать IL-код вашего свойства Distance в соответствующий SQL. Потому что Distance - это обычный метод, а не Expression Tree - и LINQ не позволяет разобрать его на отдельные вызовы `Math.Pow`, `Math.Sqrt` и сложения.

Единственный выход - как для Distance с параметрами, так и для каких-то вариантов с параметрами - вызывать сортировку уже после вытягивания данных из базы. Тогда `OrderBy` будет обработан не EF, а обычным LINQ To Objects. Т.е. вы можете написать

```
var list = dbcontext.Where(условие).ToList()
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();
```

или даже

```
var list = dbcontext.Where(условие).ToList()
                    .OrderBy(p => p.DistanceFrom(centerX, centerY).ToList();
```

что просто вызовет сортировку обычного списка объектов.

но никак не

```
var list = dbcontext.Where(условие)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();
```

Более того, если вы как-то можете сделать сортировку на стороне SQL Server, это [совсем не означает что ее стоит там делать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170187/). И на уровне базы, и на уровне приложения это будет обчыная сортировка данных в памяти. Она никак не уменьшает объем выбираемых и передаваемых данных. Сортировка на уровне базы не даст вам никаких преимуществ, скорее наоборот:

Во первых, SQL Server тратит на это CPU Time, которого в сложных приложениях обчыно не хватает, и который тяжело отмасштабировать (их-за особенной лицензирования).

Вот вторых, C# с его JIT скорее всего просто порвет сортировку по вычисляемым полям в SQL Server по производительности на сколь-либо значительном объеме.

Answer (score 3):

Есть три способа.

Способ первый - вычислять расстояние каждый раз в запросе. Выглядит сложно - но если нужна только сортировка, то можно вынести ее в отдельный метод.

```
public static IQueryable<Point> OrderByDistance(this IQueryable<Point> points, double x0, double y0) {
    return points.OrderBy(p => (p.X - x0)*(p.X - x0) + (p.Y - y0)*(p.y - y0));
}

var list = dbcontext.Points.Where(условие).OrderByDistance(x0, y0).ToList();
```

есть еще вариант - вынести отдельно метод получения выражения для расстояния:

```
public static Expression<Func<Point, double>> GetDistanceExpr(double x0, double y0) {
    return p => (p.X - x0)*(p.X - x0) + (p.Y - y0)*(p.y - y0);
}

var list = dbcontext.Points.Where(условие).OrderBy(GetDistanceExpr(x0, y0)).ToList();
```

---

Если этого не хватает, то можно воспользоваться вторым способом: завести в БД скалярную функцию, вычисляющую расстояние. Чтобы рассказать про нее EF, можно воспользоваться [`CodeFirstStoreFunctions`](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/) или [`Public Mapping API`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Public%20Mapping%20API). Получится как-то так:

```
[DbFunction("Geo", "Distance")]
public static double Distance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Эту функцию надо вызывать в запросах к БД, а не напрямую");
}

var list = dbcontext.Points.Where(условие).OrderBy(p => Distance(p.X, p.Y, x0. y0)).ToList();

//+ не забыть создать нужную функцию в БД.
```

Конечно же, для функции `Distance` можно и нормальную реализацию написать - что может оказаться удобным. Здесь я кидаю исключение просто чтобы подчеркнуть, что от тела этой функции запрос в БД не зависит.

---

Есть и третий вариант - [`DelegateDecompiler`](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler). С ним все становится еще проще:

```
[Computed]
public static double Distance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
    return (X1-X2)*(X1-X2) + (Y1-Y2)*(Y1-Y2);
}

var list = dbcontext.Points.Where(условие).OrderBy(p => Distance(p.X, p.Y, x0. y0)).Decompile().ToList();
```